# Performance impact of inflating layouts which have elements with visibility=gone

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to improve our list view rendering performance and looking into the fine tuning now. (we use viewHolder, fetch images async, pause image displaying on scroll, disabled scrolling cache already)

Now I was inspecting the layout and came across a setup like the following for the single list item's layout, which gets inflated in getView.

**getView() of custom list adapter**

```
if (convertView == null) {
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zzz_list_item, null);
  ...save stuff in holder etc.
```

**zzz_list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_success"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/base"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp" >
 ...many lines of a "success" item layout
 </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_failure"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >
  ...many lines for a failure item layout
 </LinearLayout>
```

The visibility gets controlled further down in the getView method of our custom listview adapter

**getView() method - executed every time**

```
 if(isSuccessfulItem){
   ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_failure)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
   ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_success)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 } else {
   ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_failure)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_success)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

While this also might be a small performance hog (getView is expensive), I wonder if it would make sense to refactor and split the handling for success and failure elements into two different layouts, which would then be inflated respectively using `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)`.

Does the additional failure layout code (and therefore increased file size) for my list item layout affect the performance, even if it is set to visibility=GONE during inflation?

Any insights would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the additional failure layout code (and therefore increased file
>   size) for my list item layout affect the performance, even if it is
>   set to visibility=GONE during inflation?

Either way the performance gain or loss it's minimal. A view with visibility set to `gone` doesn't need calculation in the layout and measuring phase as it's ignored but it does consume memory(and this is what you could talk about). With your current implementation even if you don't need/use the failure part of the row layout you do have it occupying memory  (multiply this by the number of rows visible on the screen). Splitting the current row in two parts will clear that memory need as each row will have only the views it actually uses.

If I were you I would implement two row types as I think it's cleaner(and it also doesn't add useless views in the memory).

You probably know this but use:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zzz_list_item, convertView, false);
```

also, cache the row views in the holder.

Comment: thanks for the insights - thats exactly what i wanted to know. We are facing some memory issues in an app, so cleaning up those views might help a bit to make the app lighter. I am aware of the inflating with specifying the root node and we are using the holder pattern, but thanks anyway for the nice tips!